# Tables not created when plugin installed

Tags: plugin-development, migration, records

I've got a plugin that works on Craft 4.5. It's been installed a long time, upgraded from 2.x to 3.x.

Now trying to use it on a new install of Craft 4.5.10, installing it does not create any tables. Below is one of the records. So, three questions:

1. In the CP Plugins page, should clicking *install* or *uninstall* create tables or remove them, respectively?
2. Is it necessary to have a migration in order for the tables to be created?
3. Any suggestions where to look for what's the problem?

Thank for any hints!

```
<?php
namespace kr37\drycalendar\records;

use Craft;
use craft\db\ActiveRecord;

class Drycalendar extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function getTableName() :string
    {   
        return '{{%drycalendar}}';
    }   

    protected function defineAttributes() {
        return array(
            // Craft automatically creates 'id' as an autoincrement
            'event_id'   => AttributeType::Number,
            'dateYmd'    => AttributeType::String,
            'timestr'    => AttributeType::String,
            'alt_text'   => AttributeType::String,
            'css_class'  => AttributeType::String,
            'userJson'   => AttributeType::String,
        );
    }

    public function defineIndexes() {
        return array(
            array('columns' => array('event_id', 'dateYmd'), 'key' => true),
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to have** [a migration in your plugin to install the necessary tables](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/migrations.html#plugin-install-migrations) and perform other plugin installation/uninstallation actions.

Just because you have a Records/Model class doesn't mean your plugin will automatically detect it and create it. You need to explicitly write this during the installation migration(`safeUp()` on the instalaltion & `safeDown()` on the uninstallation in the `*pluginName*/Install.php` file)

1. So, if your plugin has migrations, then clicking the Install/Uninstall will trigger these migrations, for example, create/drop table(s).
2. Yes!
3. Make sure your plugin actually has some kind of install/uninstall action.

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you.

Comment: I think a reason for my confusion is that this must have changed after Craft 2.0.  It seems it used to be like this: `If you add entirely new records to your plugin, the tables will automatically get created for people just installing your plugin.` From [link](https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/plugins/migrations.html)

Comment: Yep, it seems so. I didn't know that either.